# Check if a number is within a list with a tolerance error

Tags: python

I have a list like this one

```
kmean_clust= [1900.0545 , 2008.5400 , 2455.5466 , 1845.5879]
```

and I'd like to check if a certain number like "2009" lies within any of the list members with a tolerance error of 5 %

Here's my attempt but it keeps printing no

```
price =2009
    for i in range (0,len(kmean_clust)) :
        if   (kmean_clust [i] * .95) >= price >= (kmean_clust [i] * 1.05 ) : 
            print ("yes")
        else :
            print ("no")
```

Comment: Try `<=` instead of `>=`. ;-)

Comment: @MartinGal "And use len(kmean_clust) - 1.", why?

Comment: @MartinGal nice, it worked thanks! but what was the difference?

Comment: it worked without adding -1 to the length though

Comment: isn't `len(kmean_clust) = 4` and therefore the loop goes from 0 to 4? Or am I wrong?

Comment: `range(4)` is 0 to 3 inclusive.

Comment: Oh. My mistake! Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. You are comparing `low_end >= price >= high_end`. This is exactly backwards.

   You want to be comparing `low_end <= price <= high_end`.
2. You can get the whole "loop and check a condition for all entries" behavior using the built-in [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#any) function (or `all`, if that's more appropriate):

   ```
   TOLERANCE = 0.05
   LOW = 1 - TOLERANCE
   HIGH = 1 + TOLERANCE

   any_found = any(item * LOW <= price <= item * HIGH 
                   for item in kmean_clust)

   print("yes" if any_found else "no")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a sortedlist issue, your function is highly inefficient if your list is large. sortedcollections is a package that contains many optimized containers for finding elements within data. You can pull out the exact slice you are looking for with a SortedList. There are options for inclusion and exclusion as well.

```
from sortedcollections import SortedList

data = SortedList([1900.0545 , 2008.5400 , 2455.5466 , 1845.5879])
test = list(data.irange(0.95 * 2009, 1.05 * 2009)) 
if test:
    print('There are values within the range and they are',test)
else:
    print('There are no values in the given range.')
```

Note also that is operation is done very efficiently in memory, since it doesn't loop over the data and instead does a binary search.

Comment: This has some good ideas (+1) but OP's list isn't sorted and since it will be `O(n*log(n))` to sort it, it isn't clear that this is worth the price of a simple linear sweep to pick out all of the numbers that satisfy the predicate. In other words, invoking that constructor could negate any savings that this approach might otherwise have.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question. Why propose an optimization (which was not the question) and not even explain the bug in the question's code?

Answer (score 0):

```
price =2009
    for i in range (0,len(kmean_clust)) :
        if   ( (kmean_clust [i] * .95) <= price) and (price>= (kmean_clust [i] * 1.05 ) ): 
            print ("yes")
        else :
            print ("no")
```

This should resolve.

Comment: your first `>=` should by `<=`.